# Compilation error in Arduino water pump control program

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_EEPROM_I2C.h>
#include <Adafruit_FRAM_I2C.h>
#include <Servo.h> 
#include <Wire.h> 
#include "RTClib.h" 

RTC_DS3231 rtc; // create an instance of the RTC object
Servo myservo; // create an instance of the Servo object

const int servoPin = 9; // define the pin for the servo motor
const int pumpPin = 8; // define the pin for the DC water pump

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // start the serial connection
  myservo.attach(servoPin); // attach the servo to the servo pin
  pinMode(pumpPin, OUTPUT); // set the pump pin as an output
  Wire.begin(); // start the I2C communication
  rtc.begin(); // start the RTC
}

void loop() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now(); // get the current time from the RTC

  // check if it is 7:00 or 12:00
  if (now.hour() == 7 || now.hour() == 12) {
    // move the servo to the "on" position
    myservo.write(0); 
    delay(2000); // wait for 2 seconds
    // turn on the DC water pump
    digitalWrite(pumpPin, HIGH);
    delay(10000); // wait for 10 seconds
    // turn off the DC water pump
    digitalWrite(pumpPin, LOW);
    // move the servo to the "off" position
    myservo.write(180);
  }

  delay(1000); // wait for 1 second before checking the time again
}
```

That is my program, but when I try to compile it the error reads `#include <Adafruit_I2CDevice.h> Error compiling for board Arduino Uno`. Can anyone help me please? I'm just a beginner.

Comment: remove the Adafruit includes. you don't use them

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first two lines, these ones:

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_EEPROM_I2C.h>
#include <Adafruit_FRAM_I2C.h>
```

You don't use these libraries in your program, and as far as I know they are not intended for use with the Arduino Uno.